# Is there a good solution for sharing secret variables and configurations between different servers, programs and processes?

Tags: configuration, operating-system, environment-variables, distributed

Lets say you have a complex system that consists of several programs and processes running on several servers.

Now you want to change some important configuration variable like the password to a database that is used by several of these processes.

Is there a standardized solution that enables you to store these configurations at a central spot and pushes changes on update to different servers?

I imagine something like environment variables but that can be read and changed fast during runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **MQ** s(short for message queues) for distributed application communications.
**Rackspace** has a short article about different **MQ** s. Check below:

- [Using Message Queues](http://developer.rackspace.com/blog/using-message-queues-in-cloud-applications.html)

Most of these applications use **SSL** and **HTTPS** so you can have a peace of mind about the channels being secure.

Comment: Hey i stumbled upon apache Zookeeper i think it is the perfect solution: http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2013/02/how-to-use-apache-zookeeper-to-build-distributed-apps-and-why/

Comment: @SamyAteia I wasn't aware of the `Zookeeper`. But, generally you'd want to communicate distributed apps and message queues are very good for that.

Comment: I accepted your answer, but i think i will use Zookeeper for my use case. I read that you can do message queues with Zookeeper too (using sequential znodes). But i find the directory/node concept and grouping from Zookeeper more intuitive. I can then also use the ephemeral nodes to keep track if one program or system is failing.